# reduce() an array of Promises, passing the return value of each to the next

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a certain problem with Promises. I need to take a dynamic array of functions, some of which may return Promises, and call them sequentially using `.then`.

```
let fns = [
  ({name, data}) => new Promise((name, data) => {
    console.log(name, data)
    return {name, data: { ...data, logged: true}}
  }),
  ({name, data}) => ({name: name.toLowerCase(), data}),
  ({name, data}) => new Promise((name, data) => {
    setTimeout((name, data) => someAjaxFunction(name, data), 10000)
    return {name, data}
]
```

What I'm looking for is basically a `reduce` function that I can use like this:

```
Promise.resolve({name, data}).then(reduce(fns)).then(({name, data}) => doSomething(name, data))
```

So `reduce` should take an array of functions, call them sequentially passing the return value of the last via `then`, and return a Promise that resolves with the return value of the final function.

Comment: It's a function that returns a Promise. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: What you are asking is in fact an interesting question but you have other problems... `var fns = [({name, data}) => new Promise((v,x) => (console.log(name,data), v({name: name, data: data, logged: true})), bla, bla, bla ]` could have been better to start with.

Comment: None of those Promises are actually in my code. They are just examples of the type of function the reducer should accept: any function that takes one argument (an object of the form `{name, data}`) and returns either an object of the same form or a Promise that resolves to such an object.

Comment: `new Promise((name, data) => {})` means that `name` is the resolving function and `data` is the rejecting function. These parameters are not your values.

Comment: I'm sorry, that should be `Promise.resolve` instead of `new Promise`.

Comment: @GriffinYoung You should [edit] your question then

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I eventually found:

```
const reduce = (fns, init) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fns.concat([resolve]).reduce((prev, cur) => prev.then(cur), init)
  })
}
```

Comment: If "init" is a promise, you could simply do `const reduce = (fns, init) => fns.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), init);` - if it's not a promise, then `const reduce = (fns, init) => fns.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve(init));`

Answer (score 0):

Well... as i have mentioned in my comment you have an interesting to question which requires to mix up synchronous code with asynchronous yet it is doable by some means...

I might come up with a solution as follows;

```js
let fns = [({name, data}) => new Promise((v,x) => { console.log(name, data);
                                                    v({name: name, data: data, logged: true});
                                                  }),
           ({name, data}) => ({name: name.toLowerCase(), data: data}),
           ({name, data}) => new Promise((v,x) => setTimeout((n, d) => v({name: n, data: d, logged: true}), 1000, name, data))
];
var promises = fns.map(function(f){
                         var res = f({name:"x",data:[1,2,3]}); // some return promise some not
                         return res.then ? res : Promise.resolve(res); // check if they have a then method
                       });
Promise.all(promises)
       .then(ps => ps.forEach(v => console.log(v)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in full :

```
// *** 1 ***
const initialVal = {name:'x', data:'y'};
fns.reduce(function(promise, fn) {
    return promise.then(fn);
}, Promise.resolve(initialVal))
.then(function({name, data}) {
    return doSomething(name, data));
};
```

or, more compactly :

```
// *** 2 ***
const initialVal = {name:'x', data:'y'};
fns.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(fn), Promise.resolve(initialVal))
.then(({name, data}) => doSomething(name, data));
```

Or, for reusability you might choose to encapsulate the reduction in a function, say `doAsyncSequence()`, and pass in the array of functions and the initial value.

```
// *** 3 ***
function doAsyncSequence(fns, initialVal) => {
    return fns.reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(fn), Promise.resolve(initialVal));
}
// call as follows
doAsyncSequence(fns, {name:'x', data:'y'}).then(({name, data}) => doSomething(name, data));
```

Under certain cirumstances it might be more convenient to append the final function to the array of functions and allow it to be handled by the reduction :

```
// *** 4 ***
// with #3 in place
const myFinalFunction = ({name, data}) => doSomething(name, data);
const initialVal = {name:'x', data:'y'};
doAsyncSequence(fns.concat(myFinalFunction), initialVal);
```

Your own solution, which attempts to do the same as #3, has a flaw. If `init` is not thenable, then it will throw synchronously at the first iteration of the reduction. All the solutions above avoid that issue by ensuring with `Promise.resolve(initialValue)` that the start value is a promise, and avoids the need for `new Promise(...)`, which is generally expected only when promisifying functions that take callbacks.